# What's Max function-call stack size when quicksorting an array of N items with only two distinct keys

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, quicksort

Actually, this is a question from Sedgewick's Algorithm in Princeton from Coursera. I think it's ~log2(N).
But I run the experiment, when 0.5N 1s 0.5N 0s interchanged, it's ~2ln(N), when N distinct keys, it's ~2log2(N), so Why?

Here is the code from the book Algorithm 4th edition by Robert Sedgewick:

```
public class Quick 
{ 
    public static void sort(Comparable[] a)
    { 
        StdRandom.shuffle(a);  // Eliminate dependence on input.
        sort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    }

    private static void sort(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        if (hi <= lo) return;
        int j = partition(a, lo, hi); // Partition (see page 291).
        sort(a, lo, j-1);  // Sort left part a[lo .. j-1].
        sort(a, j+1, hi);  // Sort right part a[j+1 .. hi].
    }

    private static int partition(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) 
    { // Partition into a[lo..i-1], a[i], a[i+1..hi]. 
        int i = lo, j = hi+1;  // left and right scan indices
        Comparable v = a[lo];  // partitioning item
        while (true)
        {  // Scan right, scan left, check for scan complete, and exchange. 
            while (less(a[++i], v)) if (i == hi) break;
            while (less(v, a[--j])) if (j == lo) break;
            if (i >= j) break;
            exch(a, i, j);
        }
        exch(a, lo, j);  // Put v = a[j] into position 
        return j;  // with a[lo..j-1] <= a[j] <= a[j+1..hi]. 
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect this may depend on the quicksort implementation used. Did the course specify a particular one?

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen, I paste the code.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen, I run the experiment, when 0.5N 1s 0.5N 0s interchanged, it's ~2ln(N), when N distinct keys, it's ~2log2(N), could you prove it?

Comment: Take a look at pivot (`partitioning item`) selection: can it happen that for some smallish _k_, there will be at most _k_ items greater than _k_? How many nested recursive calls would you get? `Max`? What is the worst case? What is the expected case for uniform random input?

Comment: @greybeard, "Max" means the deepest size of function call stack.Well, just consider two cases: #1. 0.5N 1s 0.5N 0s interchanged, that is 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 ...; #2, N distinct keys from uniform random input.

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze it by Big O Notation it is still O(N^2) but if you'r trying to find its average complexity it may be  ~2log2(N) and AFAIK it is a bit difficult to find an algorithm's average complexity.

Comment: I run the experiment, when 0.5N 1s 0.5N 0s interchanged, it's ~2ln(N), when N distinct keys, it's ~2log2(N), could you prove it?

Comment: sorry to bother you, ^_^